# How can I specify a single target that will build multiple targets in scons?

Tags: build, scons

I want a single psuedotarget that will build multiple targets in scons.  In make, I could write:

```
binaries: foo.exe bar.exe
```

And when I `make binaries`, it would build the two `.exe` if needed.

How can I group a few targets in scons in the same way?

Answer (score 1):

Found my answer.  It's an "alias".

```
env.Alias('binaries', ['foo.exe', 'bar.exe'])
```