# Scons build system pattern-matching for targets specified on the command line

Tags: python, build, matching, scons

I am using scons for a data analysis project. Sometimes I would like to only build a subset of targets, for example all figure files (ending e.g. with ".png"). Is there a way to do this directly from the command line, like

```
scons . **/*.png
```

A manual solution I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35311446/how-can-i-specify-a-single-target-that-will-build-multiple-targets-in-scons) was adding an Alias, but this would require changing the Sconscript file for each such a subset of targets. Is there a more general way to do this?

Comment: when you run on the shell, the `**/*.png` is actually expanded by the shell. So if those files exist, you may get what you're looking for. But the correct fix is adding and Alias as Mats recommends.

Answer (score 0):

Aliases are the model for giving names to target(s) that you can invoke from the command line.  You can also use a directory name as a target, and it will build all the known targets that go under that directory.  You may not need to make changes everywhere: in your case you might be able to combine the result of calling Glob with a pattern with an alias.  Unfortunately, at the moment, Glob is not recursive (it's a wishlist item, needing someone motivated to implement it), so might be a bit of extra work if your targets of a particular type are spread all over the tree.